# Was there ever a word for 24 like "dozen" for 12?

Tags: language, numbers

The English language has more than one word for 12 (twelve, dozen) and 12^2 (one hundred and forty-four, gross), but has there ever been a word for 2*12 other than twenty-four?

I would also be interested in whether other languages developed special words for the number twenty-four.

Comment: Allegedly dozen is believed to come from the latin word duodecim ("two and ten"), and twelve from the proto-germanic word twalif ("two left over"). Thus it seems that both words are based on a decimal system.

Comment: Isn't it 4 kilobytes   ?

Comment: @markvs 4 kilobytes would be 2^12 bytes, not 2*12 bytes.

Comment: I did not notice *. Then 24 bytes or 2 dozen?

Comment: Well, right, I guess I am looking for a word that may as well mean "two dozen", but not quite as obvious as this.

Comment: Why do you think there is such a word and how would you be convinced that there isn't one?

Comment: For your votes I have been wounded more than two dozen times and been in thirty-six battles. (Shakespeare)

Comment: There is a name for 20, score, and 60, threescore.

Comment: German has "Dutzend" = 12, "Schock" = 5*12= 60, and "Gros" = 12*12 = 144, where the latter two are no longer in common use, but may be encountered in older documents. I am not aware of any special German term for 24.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the linguistics SE .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any current or archaic English word for 24 other than the obvious combinations like "double dozen" or "score and four" ("score" is 20). German style wording like "four-and-twenty" was occasionally used until 19th century, and survives in some idioms, see [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/3903).

One of the two formations (2x12 or 20+4) is typical in most languages. ["Dozen"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dozen) derives from Latin *duodecim* (2+10). Analogously, base 24 system is now called [tetravigesimal](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/dozensonline/acrobatic-tetravigesimal-base-24-t780.html) (biunqual or binilimal are rarely used) from Latin *tetra* (4) and *vigesimus* (20). But no old French or English vulgarization emerged.

Some interpret [Umbu-Ungu](https://lingweb.eva.mpg.de/channumerals/Umbu-Ungu.htm), the counting system of the [Kaugel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaugel_language) in Papua New Guinea, as base 24, although ethnologists call it 4-cycle system, see [Owens et al., History of Number: Evidence from Papua New Guinea and Oceania, p.117ff](https://www.google.com/books/edition/History_of_Number/rnQ7DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). The word for 24 in it is *tokapu*, and it is not 2x12, which would be *rurepo talu*, or 20+4 (20 is *supu* and 4 is *kise*). It is used as a root to form larger numerals.

Of course, *day* in English is 24 hours, if one chooses to see it that way. [*Nychthemeron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nychthemeron) (from Greek *núx*, night, and *hēméra*, day) is occasionally used for periods of 24 hours to remove the ambiguity, and there are similar disambiguating words in other Western languages.

Comment: biunqual, binilimal?? The etymology of these words is not obvious, and my favorite websearcher knows them from no other page than this.